# Installing packages to R from desktop

Tags: r

I am trying to install several packages to R. The packages were send to me via email from my biostatistician and I have them on my desktop in a file called R_scripts.

I have tried:

install.packages("/Users/isimee/Desktop/R_scripts/findalpha.R", repos=NULL, type="source")

Which returns following error message:

Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file
Warning message:
In install.packages("/Users/isimee/Desktop/R_scripts/findalpha.R",  :
  installation of package '/Users/isimee/Desktop/R_scripts/findalpha.R' had non-zero exit status

findalpha.R is one of the packages I am trying to install.

I am using terminal on a mac but have tried from R directly and it doesnt work. I have downloaded the devtools but doesnt work either apart from that I dont really know what to do with it.

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not believe your statistician has sent  you R packages. It seems like they sent you R scripts. Simply open these to inspect the code or use `source` to execute them.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, manual installation packages involves binary files of `.zip` or `tar.gz` files.  A `.R` file is a R code file and not a package. To use this code in your future session you just need to edit a file named `Path\to\RDirectory\etc\Rprofile.site` and include this snippet `source("path\to\codeDirectory\findalpha.R")`

Comment: Thanks to both, yes, as embarrassing as it is, it wasnt a package and problem is solved now. Thanks a lot!